# Twitter bootstrap pills

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstarp pills, Here is my HTML code :

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#one">ONE</a></li>  
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#two">TWO</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#three">THREE</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="one">
    div one content
  </div>

  <div id="two">
    div two content
  </div>

  <div id="three">
    div three content
  </div>
```

This code is showing the tab pills and also select pill while clicking on it, but not show the div corresponding to the href attribute of anchor tag.

http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/319_bootstrap_pills_tabs/Tabs-Pills-BEGIN/tabs-pills.html

Plese guide me.
Thanx

Comment: If anyone vote this question down. Please post the reason too. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer. My HTML code was not in the right format. 
Actually I was looking fro this  [image: actually I was looking fro this]
.Anyway, Thanx for answering guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want "Tabbable nav" you have to include a separate jQuery plugin. The usage is described [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to change the markup on your related content to link the tabs to the pages.

Here's a fiddle that shows the tabs working:  http://jsfiddle.net/rJxmc/